# Excel Interop: How to copy a worksheet to another workbook?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I need to merge the worksheets of some workbooks into one new workbook. What I tried is this, but I am getting "Unable to get the Copy property of the Worksheet class". What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
foreach (var sourceFileName in sourceFileNames)
{
    var sourceWorkbook = GetWorkbook(sourceFileName);

    var sourceSheet = (Worksheet)sourceWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
    var lastSheetInDestinationWorkbook = (Worksheet)_destinationWorkbook.Worksheets[_destinationWorkbook.Worksheets.Count];
    sourceSheet.Copy(After: lastSheetInDestinationWorkbook);

    sourceWorkbook.Close();
}
((Worksheet)_workbook.Sheets[1]).Delete();
_workbook.Save();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - How to copy a single Excel worksheet from one workbook to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808368/c-sharp-how-to-copy-a-single-excel-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another)

Comment: I've seen that, thanks, but no.

Comment: My crystal ball says that GetWorkbook() creates another Application object.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of psychic debugging solutions.  You've got some editing to do to make the mishap obvious, post the solution as well and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault was to load the workbooks in different Application objects. Using the same Application object solved the problem.

Thanks @HansPassant to point me there.

Comment: Please share the code fix in the answer.