# VSTO Excel Add-In - Add Worksheet from another Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I developed one VSTO Excel Add-in, To meet workflow requirement we need to replace active worksheet (it's whole content) with another excel file's worksheet.

We are planning to add one button in Excel Add-in where end user can choose another excel file which are located in their hard drive. Active worksheet will be replace with selected excel file's first worksheet.

I am stuck to copy worksheet from another excel file.

I am bit new in VSTO add-in, Can you please help me in correct direction.

Comment: Could you please point where exactly your problem is? You can't add the button? Or you have troubles with showing Open File dialog on button click? Or you don't know how to copy content from one excel workbook to another?

Comment: @Serg - I am stuck to copy worksheet from another excel file.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808368/c-sharp-how-to-copy-a-single-excel-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another for how to copy worksheet between workbooks.